# Pseudo-randomize an array whereby similar values are not consecutive

Tags: php, arrays, random

I have an array where similar values are close together. Like:

```
1: Apple 2: Big Apple 3: Small Apple 4: Green Apple 5: Orange 6: Small Orange 7: Ripe Orange
```

etc.

If I call shuffle on it the arrangement might change to:

```
1: Apple  3: Small Apple 5: Orange 4: Green Apple  6: Small Orange 2: Big Apple 7: Ripe Orange
```

As you can see most of the apples are still together. This gets worse when there are 10 elements of similar kind. Is there any way to properly randomize the location of each value? What about calling shuffle multiple times. Is there any other better way?

Comment: "I want it random but I also want to control where the elements are because I don't like the random output. Can I randomise it and make sure it ends up how I want it as well?"

Comment: This IS randomized. This is why it's output is random. You can't control it. If you could, it wouldn't be random anymore.

Comment: well....random=random right so yes it is possible it will be close to your original values BUT if its needed you can always do a check afterwards... if it doesnt pass just shuffle it again untill is passes your standards e.g. first entry in the array cant be "apple"

Comment: Similar values are still close together for example all apples. This is the main issue.How can I create more pace between them.

Comment: How do you learn, programaticaly, if some items are of the same kind? Just use the word at each item's end?

Comment: You would need to create your own algorithm in order to do what you are asking.

Comment: I've voted to close this question as Unclear.  The rules are not clearly defined and we don't have a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Presume the program is to learn the kind from the last word in each item, this is the solution. (If not, just change the logic in `kind_of()` function)

```php
<?php

// learn what kind if item is it
function kind_of($item) {
  $words = explode(' ', $item);
  return array_pop($words);
}

// reorganize as 2-dimensional array
function by_kind($input) {
  $output = array();
  foreach ($input as $item) {
    $output[kind_of($item)][] = $item;
  }
  return $output;
}


$input = array(
  'Orange',
  'Apple',
  'Big Apple',
  'Small Orange',
  'Small Apple',
  'Ripe Orange',
  'Green Apple',
);

// arrange the items in 2-dimensional by_kind array
// then shuffle each second level arrays
$by_kind = by_kind($input);
ksort($by_kind); // sort by key (kind name)
$shuffled_by_kind = array_map(function ($kind_items) {
  shuffle($kind_items);
  return $kind_items;
}, $by_kind);

// merge the second level arrays back to 1 array
$result = call_user_func_array('array_merge', array_values($shuffled_by_kind));

// see output
var_dump($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the working example of what you need:

```
public function shuffle_assoc(&$array) {
    $keys = array_keys($array);

    shuffle($keys);

    foreach($keys as $key) {
        $new[$key] = $array[$key];
    }

    $array = $new;

    return true;
}

$fruits = array(
    1 => 'Apple ',
    2 => 'Big Apple ',
    3 => 'Small Apple ',
    4 => 'Green Apple ',
    5 => 'Orange ',
    6 => 'Small Orange ',
    7 => 'Ripe Orange',
);
shuffle_assoc($fruits);
echo "<pre>"; var_dump($fruits); die;
```